# How to constantly read FIFO in C

Tags: c, fifo

I want to read a fifo pipe constantly in C.
My code example works, but since i use while(1) one of my CPU cores is at 100% all the time.

So my question: Is there a smoother way to read the fifo, without killing the CPU?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool suffix (char* base, char* str) {
    int blen = strlen(base);
    int slen = strlen(str);
    return (blen >= slen) && (0 == strcmp(base + blen - slen, str));
}

bool prefix(const char *pre, const char *str)
{
    return strncmp(pre, str, strlen(pre)) == 0;
}


void chomp(char *s) {
    while(*s && *s != '\n' && *s != '\r') s++;
    *s = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fifo, c=0;
    char buf[200];

    char fifo_name[] = "/var/log/proftpd_log_all.fifo";
    fifo = open(fifo_name, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);

    while (1)
    {
        if (read(fifo, &buf, sizeof(char)*200) > 0)
        {
            if (prefix("[STOR]",buf)) {
                //printf("%s \n", buf);
                if (strstr(buf, ".jpf") != NULL) {
                    //...
                }       
            }
        }
    }
    printf("exit");
    close(fifo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to read it in a loop while not doing anything else, why are you making it non-blocking? Just make it blocking. Problem solved.

Comment: Rephrase your question: I want to read from a fifo and not do anything until data is available.  Rephrase again: I want to read from a fifo and block on the read.  The solution (given by Dark Falcon) then becomes obvious.  Don't open non-blocking.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: Or, if your code is fancier than this example, use `select(2)` or `poll(2)` to multitask properly.

Comment: if i remove the O_NONBLOCK, i`am still on 100% CPU

Comment: OK, so when you run it under a debugger, what did you find was looping?  Is it still the read() loop?

Comment: strstr(buf..) what is in buf when this is called?  Is there a valid null-terminated string in it?

Comment: Same with strlen(pre).

Comment: at the moment the line with the strstr(buf is not called, because i`am not writing to the fifo. when i set some breaks it is jumping between the first two if statements.

Comment: If you are not writing to the fifo and you removed O_NONBLOCK then it should not use any CPU... Something else is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 methods for handling it:-

1. You can use Blocking mode while reading from FIFO.
2. Simplest method is to use sleep() within the while loop to suspend the thread for sometime , this would reduce cpu load momentarily.
3. You can use signals & interrupts,writer can send a signal whenever it writes something to FIFO.The reader can be suspended until a signal is received from the writer of FIFO & performs the read operation until end of FIFO and suspends again.

Comment: 3: Don't pass `O_NONBLOCK` to `open()`.

Comment: Also, don't suggest sleep() loops for polling I/O.  It's wasteful of CPU and memory bandwidth, as well as adding avoidable latency.  Answers like that give sleep() a bad name - it should be reserved for when a delay is actually necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I'd use `select()` for polling. You can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int main()
{
    fd_set readCheck;
    fd_set errCheck;
    char buffer[64];
    struct timeval timeout;
    int rv;

    int fd = open("./fifo.test", O_RDONLY | O_RSYNC);

    FD_ZERO(&readCheck);
    FD_ZERO(&errCheck);

    while (1) {
        FD_SET(fd, &readCheck);
        FD_SET(fd, &errCheck);

        timeout.tv_sec = 1;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        rv = select(fd, &readCheck, NULL, &errCheck, &timeout);
        if (rv < 0) {
            printf("Select failed\r\n");
            break;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &errCheck)) {
            printf("FD error\r\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &readCheck)) {
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
            rv = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            if (rv < 0) {
                printf("Read failed\r\n");
                break;
            }
            buffer[63] = '\0';
            printf(buffer);
        }
    }
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

It should work for FIFO files, created with `mkfifo()`.
You can also set infinite timeout with `NULL` instead of `timeout` in function call.

This will reduce your CPU utilization greatly and will allow you to read only real data.
Take note that if you use a simple file instead of a FIFO the `select()` function will wait forever for it to update, because simple files are always ready to read.

You can also read the following mans for more info: `select, pselect, poll`

Comment: `char buffer[64];  ... buffer[64] = '\0';`  leads to problems.

Comment: Yes, it could, but I had no intention to demonstrate how to work with simple character buffer.